# How is deprecated.legacy-timestamp supposed to work in Presto 0.220?

Tags: amazon-emr, presto, trino

I'm encountering an issue with reading timestamps properly, without any automatic conversions on Presto on EMR.

Example: within the AWS Glue catalog, i have a table with timestamp columns in UTC time (data type timestamp). When querying in Athena, they return as expected. When querying in Presto on EMR (EMR 5.26, Presto 0.220), there is an automatic conversion happening to a different time zone.

Presto docs describe a method of disabling this behavior here - https://prestosql.io/docs/current/language/timestamp.

`The legacy semantics can be enabled using the deprecated.legacy-timestamp config property. Setting it to true (the default) enables the legacy semantics, whereas setting it to false enables the new semantics.`

They outline their result differences with this option set to true vs false at the bottom

`Query: SELECT TIME '10:00:00 Asia/Kathmandu' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
Legacy result: 04:30:00.000 UTC
New result: 04:15:00.000 UTC`

After including `deprecated.legacy-timestamp` set to `true` in my EMR config (within presto-config), I'm still getting the new result according to this test query, (and my UTC timestamps are still being auto converted).

Any suggestions on what else i need to do to enable the legacy timestamp behavior?

Comment: Legacy timestamp behavior is still the default, you can track it here: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/37. Hive connector doesn't support the new timestamp semantics, so in your case switching the toggle doesn't change match. What you probably want is switching client session zone to UTC. Since Presto 317 you can also ignore session zone and force UTC for all clients. See https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-317.html > `sql.forced-session-time-zone`.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen thank you for the explanation. the session zone doc is a bit unclear. am i supposed to be including `sql.forced-session-time-zone:UTC` along with the other `presto-config` settings (like query.max-memory, optimizer.optimize-metadata-queries etc.)? that seems to break presto

Comment: Exactly. This breaks Presto because you're using an older Presto version. I'd recommend that you ask your AWS support when will Presto 317 be available on EMR. For now, you need to make sure your client uses UTC zone. This can be done by running the process with `-Duser.timezone=UTC`. How do you connect to Presto? CLI/JDBC/ODBC?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen ahh that makes sense. i'm currently connecting via `presto-cli`

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen your suggestion to use `-Duser.timezone=UTC` works perfectly. i'm using `presto-cli --catalog hive --user -Duser.timezone=UTC` to make this work. EMR 5.27 was released today with Presto 0.224, since the updates are monthly, it will be at least a month until the next one. Although, i'm not sure when they'll go from 0.224 prestodb to 317 prestosql. Will inquire about that.

Comment: Thanks for update. I will convert my comment into an answer, so it doesn't hang unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legacy timestamp behavior is still the default, you can track current state at https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/37. Apparently Athena evaluates timestamps as Presto would do when run with UTC session zone.

Since Presto 317 you can force client session zone with a config property:

```
 sql.forced-session-time-zone=UTC
```

For all Presto versions, you can set client session zone. How to do this depends on the particular client in use. For example, with `presto-cli` you would typically do

```
java -Duser.timezone=UTC -jar presto-cli.jar
```